# PostgreSQL: Pegar quantidade de erros e acertos

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Preciso de uma query para pegar quantidade de erros e acertos dessa tabela.
[image: Dabela com dados]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo do gênero:

```
SELECT t.acertou,
       COUNT(1)
  FROM tabela t
 GROUP BY t.acertou
```

Caso queria mostrar como apenas um registro, você pode utilizar `subquery`:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM tabela t
         WHERE t.acertou) AS acertos,
       (SELECT COUNT(1)
          FROM tabela t
         WHERE NOT t.acertou) AS erros
```

Comment: show.... funcionou aqui...
mas como faço para pegar cada um em uma coluna?

Comment: @ThiagoCunha depende, você quer filtrar por aluno ou como quer fazer? Tudo de uma vez?

Comment: precisava somente de 2 colunas... 1 mostrando o valor de quantidade de acertos, e outra, com a quantidade de erros...

Comment: @ThiagoCunha alterei a resposta com base na sua dúvida

Comment: TOP! Valeu mesmo! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta baseado em sua dúvida a respeito da execução. Se eu quiser pegar agrupado por aluno? Ou seja, mostrar:
qtd_erros_aluno, qtd_acertos_aluno

Comment: @ThiagoCunha aí a resposta ia mudar radicalmente. Se você quiser fazer outra pergunta com essa dúvida eu posso bolar uma `query` que atenda

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299105/query-para-pegar-erros-e-acertos-de-um-aluno