# Query para pegar Erros e acertos de um aluno

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, query

Gostaria de uma query para pegar erros e acertos de um determinado aluno da seguinte tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para chegar no resultado desejado você pode criar uma `query` agrupada pela `matricula_aluno` e utilizar a função `COUNT` em conjunto com um `CASE` testando a coluna `acertou`:

```
SELECT r.matricula_aluno,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN acertou THEN 1 END) AS acertos,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT acertou THEN 1 END) AS erros
  FROM realizacao r
 GROUP BY r.matricula_aluno
```

Veja funcionando no [SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/08c59/2)

Comment: Show! Vlw mais uma vez! :)